# how to query from update handler javascript code

Tags: javascript, couchdb, fauxton

What I'm trying to do:

1. I want to add data (id, data) to db. While doing so, I want to check if the id already exists and if so, append to existing data. else add a new (id, data) entry.

Ex: This could be a db of student id and grades in multiple tests. If an id exists in the db already, I want to just append to the existing test scores already in db, else create a new entry: (id, grades)

2. I have setup an update handler function to do this. I understand, couchdb insert by default does not do the above. Now - how do I check the db for that id and if so, decide to whether to add a new entry or append. I know there is db.get(). However, I presume since the update handler function is already part of the db itelf, there may be a more efficient way of doing it.

I see this sample code in the couchdb wiki:

```
function(doc, req){
    if (!doc){
        if ('id' in req && req['id']){
            // create new document
            return [req, 'New Document'];
        }
        // change nothing in database
        return [null, 'Incorrect data format'];
    }
    doc[id] = req;
    return [doc, 'Edited World!'];
}
```

a few clarifications in this example that's not clear: where do we get the id from? Often the id is not explicitly passed in while adding to db.

Does that mean, we need to explicitly pass a field called "_id"?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I check the db for that id and if so, decide to whether to add a new entry or append.

CouchDB does this for you, assuming HTTP client triggers your update function using the ID. As the [documentation describes](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/ddocs.html#update-functions):

> When the request to an update handler includes a document ID in the URL, the server will provide the function with the most recent version of that document

In the sample code you found, the update function looks like `function(doc, req)` and so in the code inside of that function the variable `doc` will have the *existing* document already "inside" your CouchDB database. All the incoming data from the client/user will be found [somewhere within `req`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/json-structure.html#request-object).

So for your case it might look something like:

```
function(doc, req){
  if (doc) {
    doc.grades.push(req.form.the_grade);
    return [doc, "Added the grade to existing document"];
  } else {
    var newDoc = {_id:req.uuid, grades:[req.form.the_grade]};
    return [newDoc, "Created new document ("+newDoc._id+") for the grade"];
  }
}
```

If the client does a POST to `/your_db/_design/your_ddoc/_update/your_update_function/existing_doc_id` then the first part of the `if (doc)` will be triggered, since you will have gotten the existing document (pre-fetched for you) in the `doc` variable. If the client does a POST to just `/your_db/_design/your_ddoc/_update/your_update_function`, then there is no `doc` provided and you must create a new one (`else` clause).

Note that the client **will** need to know the ID to update an existing document. Either track it, look it up, or — if you must and understand the drawbacks — make them determinate based on something that is known.

---

Aside: the `db.get()` you mentioned is probably from a CouchDB *HTTP client* library and is not availble (and would not work) in the context of any update/show/list/etc. functions that are running sandboxed in the database "itself".

Answer (score 0):

Cited from the documentation:

> If you are updating an existing document, it should already have an _id set, and if you are creating a new document, make sure to set its _id to something, either generated based on the input or the req.uuid provided. The second element is the response that will be sent back to the caller.

So **tl;dr**, if the _id is not specified, use `req.uuid`.

Documentation link: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/ddocs.html#update-functions